# Contact form for free

Tags: add-on, bootstrap, email-contact-form

How can I transform a HTML form in a template into an email that someone can receive after they fill it out with any paid add-ons? If I need an add-on for that, can anyone suggest any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a free version of Freeform.
https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform

Answer (score 3):

There is a contact form bundled with ExpressionEngine: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/email/contact_form.html